# Is there a tool or a way to automatically make all GET fetch requests API endpoints in controller in Java based on POST JSON data

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I was working on making some `REST` APIs for inserting data through POST requests. Now I need to make `GET` `REST`APIs for fetching purpose on same `JSON` data that I used to POST the data in DB.

[image]

Is there any tool exist which can help me creating those `REST` GET APIs? I am working on `spring boot` environment. Is there a way to automatically create those GET endpoints in my controller, based on the data that I used during POST requests? Otherwise it would be a very tedious work to make GET API end point for fetching data on each and every field. Can any one guide me..

Comment: Well [Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) might help you, but you have existing POST call don't think you can avoid while creating them.

Comment: Why do you need to make a new GET endpoint for every field?  If I understand correctly, you can add the fields as query params and then just define a single GET endpoint.  Inside that handler method you can access the query params and search based on them.